vscodeで「定義へ移動」が出てこない
vscodeで定義へ移動が出てきません。言語はC++。どうすれば良いでしょうか？
現状
画像は変数名を選択した状態で右クリックで表示されるポップアップメニュー。"定義へ移動"が表示されていない。(定義へ移動は、その変数や関数が定義されている箇所へジャンプできる機能）

期待する動作
ポップアップメニューに "定義へ移動" の選択肢が表示される
環境
Ubuntu 20.04
Visual studio code v1.94.0

閲覧者はここに書いてないこと以外は知り得ないということを認識してますか？　質問者さんの PC の OS とか、VS Code のバージョンとか、拡張機能に何を入れているかとか、質問に貼った画像をどうやって出したかとか、質問者さんの言う「定義へ移動」というのは何かとか・・・

この辺の記事での拡張機能等のインストールと設定の関連なのでは？あるいは対象ファイルがC++用と認識されていないとか？ C++環境構築メモ （Mac, VSCode, GCC, 競プロ）, 競技プログラミングC++環境構築 (macOS) 2023年版, VSCode で C/C++ を書く環境を用意するメモ（macOS）, VSCode C/C++のIntelli senseが効かなくなった話, C++開発を強化する: プログラマー必見のVSCode拡張機能トップ10

あと当てはまるか分からないのと英語ですが、関連性が高そうな記事がこちら。Jumping to Header Files in Visual Studio Code for C/C++ Projects

@kunif さん、情報提供ありがとうございます！記事を見ながら設定を見直したところ無事に所望の機能を使えるようになりました。

@WebSurfer すでに解決しましたが、状況説明の詳細を追記しました。いただいたコメントの内容については、今後、参考にさせていただきます。ありがとうございます

解決しました。
C/C++ 拡張機能がインストールされていたが無効になっており、有効にすると表示されるようになりました。
( @kunif さんありがとうございました )
現状（解決後）

有効にした拡張機能

